# How do I clear the DNS cache in Windows 10 version 1709?

Tags: dns, windows-10-v1709

Probably the easiest way to clear the cache would be to restart the DNS Client service, but the option is grayed out even if I load the Services window as SYSTEM through PsExec. If I use something such as, say, `IPCONFIG  /FLUSHDNS`, it says it works but actually it doesn't help at all. Is there a way to force Windows to clear the DNS cache for real?? [I swear, how in the heck is the restriction of the DNS service useful in any way??]

Comment: ipconfig /flushdns is the way to go. If that isn't working, something else is going wrong on your end. You may have to clear your browser cache for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press the Windows key to the side of the space bar on the keyboard, or click the Windows menu on the side of the Taskbar on the screen.

Enter 'cmd', right-click on the Command Prompt, and choose 'Run as Administrator'.  Click Yes.

Enter 'ping www.mydomain' with the name of the domain or host that needs to be verified.

Enter 'ipconfig /flushdns'.

Enter 'ping www.mydomain' again to see the current results of the DNS request.